# How to communicate when a packet starts and ends (send two bytes in one packet)

Tags: usb, keyboard

I am aware that there are some libraries around this topic and that it would be easy to make this type of keyboard if I'll use different kind of arduino. I am doing it for learning purposes and couldn't find the solution online.

[image]

```
//Array that holds 8 bits that needs to be sent
uint8_t buf[8] = {0};
#define Pin_A 13

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Pin_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() 
  {
    if(digitalRead(Pin_A) == LOW)
    {
      buf[2]=4;
      Serial.write(buf,8);
      buf[2]=5;
      Serial.write(buf,8);
    }
  }
```

In order to turn the keyboard into a HID device I am using Arduino-keyboard-0.3, but I believe it is irrelevant.

As you can see, it looks like I need to find a way to send both keycodes in one packet. I know that there aren't any hardware limitations since [this](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) library turns the uno into a keyboard that can press 6 buttons continually

Comment: The first comment in your code is incorrect, that's an 8 byte buffer not 8 bits. And you're only setting one of them. Isn't that suspicious? Where did you find that you needed to send 8 bytes? Can't you find some clues there as to what you're supposed to put in there?

Comment: @MAt Oh. wow you are right. I changed the one of them to be [2] and one [3] and now they are both being held when pressed. So apparently I'm not sending bits but just sending out keycodes that this bootloader happens to understand?